# Map multiple functions to CSV rows

Tags: python

I'm trying to do some type conversions on CSV data that is comprised entirely of strings. I was thinking I'd use a dictionary of header names to functions and map those functions over each CSV row. I'm just a little stuck on how to efficiently map multiple functions to a row. I was thinking of enumerating the headers and creating a new dictionary of indices to functions:

```
header_map = {'Foo':str,
              'Bar':str,
              'FooBar':float}

csv_data = [('Foo', 'Bar', 'FooBar'),
            #lots of data...
           ]

index_map = {}

#enumerate the rows and create a dictionary of index:function
for i, header in enumerate(csv_data[0]):
    index_map[i] = header_map[header]

#retrieve the function for each index and call it on the value
new_csv = [[index_map[i](value) for i, value in enumerate(row)] 
           for row in csv_data[1:]]
```

I'm just curious if anyone knows of simpler, efficient way to accomplish this type of operation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a method, `using_converter`,  which is slightly faster:

```
import itertools as IT

header_map = {'Foo':str,
              'Bar':str,
              'FooBar':float}

N = 20000
csv_data = [('Foo', 'Bar', 'FooBar')] + [('Foo', 'Bar', 1123.451)]*N

def original(csv_data):
    index_map = {}
    #enumerate the rows and create a dictionary of index:function
    for i, header in enumerate(csv_data[0]):
        index_map[i] = header_map[header]

    #retrieve the appropriate function for each index and call it on the value
    new_csv = [[index_map[i](value) for i, value in enumerate(row)]
               for row in csv_data[1:]]
    return new_csv

def using_converter(csv_data):
    converters = IT.cycle([header_map[header] for header in csv_data[0]])
    conv = converters.next
    new_csv = [[conv()(item) for item in row] for row in csv_data[1:]]
    return new_csv

def using_header_map(csv_data):
    heads = csv_data[0]
    new_csv = [
        tuple(header_map[head](item) for head, item in zip(heads, row))
        for row in csv_data[1:]]
    return new_csv

# print(original(csv_data))
# print(using_converter(csv_data))
# print(using_header_map(csv_data))
```

---

Benchmarking with `timeit`:

The original code:

```
% python -mtimeit -s'import test' 'test.original(test.csv_data)'
100 loops, best of 3: 17.3 msec per loop
```

A slightly faster version (using itertools):

```
% python -mtimeit -s'import test' 'test.using_converter(test.csv_data)'
100 loops, best of 3: 15.5 msec per loop
```

Lev Levitsky's version:

```
% python -mtimeit -s'import test' 'test.using_header_map(test.csv_data)'
10 loops, best of 3: 36.2 msec per loop
```

Answer (score 1):

Didn't test (no sample input), but this seems to do what you want:

```
heads = csv_data[0]
new_csv = heads + [
              tuple(header_map[head](item) for head, item in zip(heads, row))
          for row in csv_data[1:]]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know order of titles in header, you can use list of functions instead of dict,

```
>>> header = [str, str, float]
>>> csv = [("aaa", "bbb", "3.14")] * 10
>>> map(lambda line: map(lambda f, arg: f(arg), header, line), csv)
[['aaa', 'bbb', 3.14], ['aaa', 'bbb', 3.14], ...
```